# In Word, how can I retain merge source (from text file) when I reopen document

Tags: microsoft-word, merge

I have been doing simple mail merge in Word (latest version) using a CSV text document as data source.

This works, I can assign fields, and do mail merge.

But when I open the word document next time, I *always* get this warning:

[image: warning about SQL command from text file]

The text translates in English to "If you open this document, the following SQL command is executed: (select * from... .txt). Do you wish to continue".

It does not matter what I respond, after this I am warned "Word can not find data source".

The only thing I can do is to remove the data source, then go to merge->external data->select text file (again) and load.

However, the data file reference *IS* there and referenced by exact name in the document `word\_rels\settings.xml` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
  <Relationship Id="rId1" 
      Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/mailMergeSource" 
      Target="file:///C:\XXXXXXX\Documents\Datakilder\UnicodeMailDatabase.txt" 
      TargetMode="External"/>
</Relationships>
```

Do I not understand data sources in word ? Or did I miss a setting ?

Comment: Use `regedit` and position to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options` (assuming you're on Office 2016 or later). Do you have an item named `SQLSecurityCheck`? If you do, does it help to set its value to zero? ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-receive-the-opening-this-will-run-the-following-sql-command-message-when-you-open-a-word-mail-merge-main-document-that-is-linked-to-a-data-source-aebb9d4b-003c-0d4b-2762-42ecdccbaced))

Comment: I will try this, and yes this is 2016/office 365. Except the text states `"Note If you click Yes, the mail merge main document opens with the data source attached."` If I click YES, I only get a warning that datasource is not found.  Word not being able to (re)option an ascii text file. ..